# Plot Cstr equation

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I need help getting the right plot for `tau` as a function of `c` (conversion).

Here's my code:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *
from scipy.optimize import root

def tau(c,T = 298):
    ci = 2
    pw = 1000
    Cp = 4
    k0 = 0.01
    e = 1000
    Hr = (-3*10**4)
    a = np.linspace(0,10000,10000)
    t = np.zeros(len(a))

    for i in range(len(a)):
        t[i] = (ci * k0 * exp(e/298))/(ci - c[i])
    plt.plot(t,c)
    plt.show()
print(tau(np.linspace(0,1,10000)))
```

My plot is not correct.

How do I modify my equation to get the following kind of plot?

[image: C vs T]

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say why your plot of conversion is incorrect without knowing the original problem statement. Can you please provide more information? Your plot of conversion does increase with residence time (tau), which it should do. It looks like you've defined some constants that are unused, such as the enthalpy of reaction (Hr), pw, and the temperature. At any rate, it is apparent that your question is not about python or plotting, but rather about how to correctly solve a chemical engineering reactor design problem.